# find third largest word in array - CoderByte - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to JS and am trying out CoderByte. The problem below I have gone around in circles trying to figure it out. I am stuck on how to get to the third largest word. Thanks in advance for the guidance.

Problem from [CoderByte](http://coderbyte.com/CodingArea/GuestEditor.php?ct=Third%20Greatest&lan=JavaScript)

Using the JavaScript language, have the function ThirdGreatest(strArr) take the array of strings stored in strArr and return the third largest word within in. So for example: if strArr is ["hello", "world", "before", "all"] your output should be world because "before" is 6 letters long, and "hello" and "world" are both 5, but the output should be world because it appeared as the last 5 letter word in the array. If strArr was ["hello", "world", "after", "all"] the output should be after because the first three words are all 5 letters long, so return the last one. The array will have at least three strings and each string will only contain letters.

```
var arr = ["hello", "world", "before", "all"]; => world   sorted = ["all", "hello", "world", "before"]
var arr2 = ["hello", "world", "after", "all"]; => after   sorted = ["all", "hello", "world", "after"]
var arr3 = ['all', 'mary', 'jenn', 'frank', 'marshall', 'bob', 'sam', 'may']; => sorted = ["marshall", "frank", "mary", "jenn", "all", "bob", "sam", "may"]

var thirdGreatest = function (arr) {
    var arr2 = arr.sort(function(a,b){ return b.length - a.length});
    return arr2;
};
```

Comment: strArr was ["hello", "world", "after", "all"] => after , but after is 4th largest, after "all", "hello", "world", right?

Comment: Can you describe the condition returning the third item from the sorted array violates?

Comment: @Andrew - ya that is correct, although that is not what the problem states. it says that 'after' is the 'third largest'

Comment: @Maus - if you look at `arr3` the patter is not the same as `'jenn'` should be the third largest, even though she may be 4th in the list.

Comment: @jstone, you mean you need to find the in strs with the largest length, which will be ["hello", "world", "after"], and pick the 3rd one. But if so, what about there's only one largest str

Comment: @Andrew that is a good case scenario to throw in. The coderbyte problem just factor in all the scenarios. Just how they write it. So it can be a bit ambiguous at times.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there, one sorted, just return the third item from the array:

```
var thirdGreatest = function (arr) {
    var arr2 = arr.sort(function(a,b){ return b.length - a.length});
    return arr2[2];
};
```

Remembering that arrays are zero indexed!

Comment: I don't think this is right. As the results for each of the arrays are different if you look at the problem more closely. It's actually a tricky one because it is not just the third item of the array.

Comment: This is sorting by the length of each string in the array - the callback to sort() is called on each pair of elements in the array. If the callback is negative, a is longer so should be after b. If the callback is zero they are the same length, so their positions are fine. If the callback is positive, b is longer and b should be after a.

Comment: As it is sorted already, returning the third entry in the sorted array will be the third longest word.

Comment: If the array is big, sorting will be slow. See my answer for a quicker solution.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting is expensive, and it might change the order of words of equal length. Additionally, we're only interested in the length of words, not in their alphabetical order.

This piece of code returns the correct results on every case given at CoderByte:

```
function ThirdGreatest(strArr) { 
  longest = '';
  second = '';
  third = '';
  for (idx in strArr) {
    current = strArr[idx];
    if (current.length > longest.length) {
      third = second;
      second = longest;
      longest = current;
    } else if (current.length > second.length) {
      third = second;
      second = current;
    } else if (current.length >= third.length) {
      third = current;
    }
  }
  return third;          
}
```

It keeps the longest three words seen so far, and if it encounters a word longer than any of the three, it pushes the shorter ones out.

In the final else if statement, making ">" into >=" ensures that the third longest string will always be the latest string in the array if there are multiple with the same length

Answer (score 0):

Why not just sort it then get the third item of the array?

```
var thirdGreatest = function (arr) {
    // sorts the array
    var arr2 = arr.sort();

    // gets the third item (third largest)
    return arr2[2];
};
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. As the results for each of the arrays are different if you look at the problem more closely. It's actually a tricky one because it is not just the third item of the array.

Comment: Sort won't compare the lengths of the elements in the array without a callback.

Comment: Returns `"hello"` for input `["hello", "world", "before", "all"]`  :-(